# Nodejs and/or PHP mobile detection

Tags: node.js, express, mobile

Is there a good and reliable library or method, or whatever, that can detect if the request is coming from a mobile environment?

I found a few packages, but non seems to work properly. I am looking for a basic/simple one that is able to detect just this: isMobile; isDesktop. Needs to be reliable, up to date and working.

If there is none free, even payed solutions would be acceptable. I am not looking for 100% detection, but I expect that top most popular devices to be detected without problem.

I am looking for a nodejs (express) solution, and/or a PHP one.

Comment: Did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834467/nodejs-and-or-php-mobile-detection/40834603#40834603) help you? Any comments?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the answer. I have noticed that is quite a complicated problem to detect the device, mostly it reduced to what you want the answer for.

Answer (score 2):

DeviceAtlas has a good article:
[How to detect a mobile browser](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/how-to-detect-mobile-browser) by Pawel Piejko.

They have examples with PHP, Java and Python and they have API to use. It is a a paid service but with free trial.

Mobile detection is a complicated problem. Of course it's easy to detect an iPhone with some client-side JavaScript, but mobile devices are not only iPhones or Android phones. And if you want to detect it before running client-side JavaScript like you need here then you cannot rely only on client-side JavaScript.

### More options

General options:

[WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/), [51Degrees](https://51degrees.com/), [OpenDDR](https://github.com/OpenDDRdotORG/OpenDDR-Resources), [MobileESP](http://blog.mobileesp.com/), [ua-parser](https://github.com/ua-parser), [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/).

Node modules:

[mobile-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobile-detect),
[device-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/device-detect),
[detect-mobile-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-mobile-browser),
[sniffr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sniffr),
[dagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dagent),
[device-detective](https://www.npmjs.com/package/device-detective),
[ismobilejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ismobilejs).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed analysis and listing the most popular solutions both commercial and Open Source. You mentioned the legacy version of OpenDDR data/resources. Which works fine, so there's nothing wrong with it. A fairly backward-compatible fork of OpenDDR exists under Apache DeviceMap (http://devicemap.apache.org/, it's archived to Apache Attic, so active development stopped) but the most recent  and active successor to OpenDDR can be found here: https://github.com/OpenDDRmobi/openddr-data. More to come on http://openddr.mobi.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP you can use [Mobile-detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/). According to its official description in Github, Mobile_Detect is a lightweight PHP class for detecting mobile devices.

For node.js you can use [mobile-detect.js](https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js). It's a port of Mobile-detect to javascript.